# how to add the quotes to the object

Tags: python, object, quote

I want to add the quotes to the object.

For example,

[As-is]

```
a = 100
```

[To-be]

```
a = '100'
```

Please somebody help me.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You can use `str` to convert an integer to a string.  However, `print(100)` and `print('100')` produce exactly the same output.  What is the larger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The object doesn't have any quotes. This is *crucial* to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes around a value simply indicate that it is a string. If you want to convert an object to a string you can simply use the `str()` function like so

```
a = 100
b = str(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = 100
a = str(a)
a # outputs '100'
```